# Swift post data from WebView to native app

Tags: javascript, html, swift, webview, pass-data

I have created an HTML file containing `userName` and `password` fields and a submit button. by pressing Submit button a JavaScript function is called to return the `userName` value. I have a native app containing a label in top and a WebView. The WebView is rendered with that HTML file. I need to send the username in WebView as the label's text in ViewController. I tried to use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` function of `UIWebViewDelegate` but it doesn't work for my problem as I need to pass data after Submit button pressed not when the WebView finished loading as this time no data has been entered yet in the userName's field !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:
I used 'Form' element to create a form with including username, password and submit button and in Swift app I used shouldStartLoadWith request of WebView's Delegate function. Each time that Submit button is tapped this function is called to access the Form elements. Then I called stringByEvaluatingJavaScript function to access the javascript function in HTML file. Here is the code:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.formSubmitted) {

        // form is submitted or button is clicked , perform your actions here

        //let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('form1').elements[0].value")!

        let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.myFunc()")!

        lbl.text = result

    }

    return true
}
```

And here is the HTML file:

```
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" action="myFunc()" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

First name:<br>

<input type="text" name="username" id="user">

<br>

Password:<br>

<input type="password" name="password">

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<Script>

function myFunc(){

var user = document.getElementById('form1').elements[0].value;

//document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = user;

return user;

}

function validateForm() {

var x = document.forms["form1"]["username"].value;

var y = document.forms["form1"]["password"].value;

if (x == "") {

    alert("Name must be filled out");

    return false;
}

if (y == "") {

    alert("Password must be filled out");

    return false;
}

if (x== "" && y == "") {

    alert("Fields must be filled out");

    return false;
}

}

</Script>

</body>
```